# Documents required for Korean minor traveling alone to Norway

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, norway, minors, us-residents

I'm a Korean citizen with an American green card trying to go to Norway for the summer vacation. I'm 17 years old and I plan to travel by myself. I'm wondering what are the documents I need in order to enter Norway? I've been looking for the past 2 days but haven't come across a solid answer. There have been mixed answers online and I hope someone here can finally help me out.

edit: i intend on taking norwegian air

Comment: Which airline are you intending to fly on?  Different airlines have different policies about unaccompanied minors.  This may be in addition to whatever you need to enter Norway.

Comment: Norway is in the Schengen area and South Korea is a Schengen Annex II country -- no visa required (I'm assuming you're from the ROK and not the DPRK). So the only problem is your minor status.

Comment: Norwegian Air’s policy says that minors 15+ years old travel as an adult https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/travelling-with-children/children-travelling-alone/ You’ll need to be able to show suitable evidence of means https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf#29

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you’re from South Korea, you do not need a visa to visit Norway for up to 90 days. However, in trying to determine what documents it may be advisable for you to take with you on your trip, a good rule of thumb is to have available the same documents you’d use to apply for a visa to show to Immigration officers if asked. A list for Norway is available here https://www.norway.no/contentassets/a7bc30faaf4144788590ef48e8a7c750/document-checklist-visitors-visa.pdf

Your personal circumstances will guide which documents are relevant. This might typically include, for example:

- passport, valid for at least 3 months beyond your planned date of return
- proof of legal residence in the US
- documents demonstrating intention to leave and means of support during your trip (accommodation, financial - see https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf#29)
- travel medical insurance, coverage at least €30,000. See the visa documents checklist for other minimum requirements.
- a notarised letter of consent from parent(s) authorising travel, if under 18 (Note: I could not find any definitive reference to this as a mandatory requirement for visa-free entrants. I recommend you check with the local Norwegian Embassy/Consulate).